# How to configure apache so that it can listen on another host?

Tags: apache-2.2

Now apache is listening on hostA,how to make it also listen on hostB too?

I've already pointed hostA and hostB to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In advance

If you point `hostA` and `hostB` to 127.0.0.1 you will only be able to connect to the server from localhost. (*Just wanted to put a finger on it, from now on I assume this is your intention*)

#### Now to your question

If you would like to use two different adresses pointing to one directory you will look for something like

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hostA
    ServerAlias hostB www.hostA www.hostB
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise if you would like to use different document roots (also known as name based virtual hosting) you will need to use something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hostA
    ServerAlias www.hostA
    DocumentRoot /www/hostA
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hostB
    ServerAlias www.hostB
    DocumentRoot /www/hostB
</VirtualHost>
```